# grails datepicker

Tags: grails, datepicker

I'm using g:datePicker name="date1" id="date1" value="${program?.startDate}" >

In controller when  used params.date1 it is showing value as "struct" and unable to save date in my database.

How can we parse date in to one param like eg: 2010-10-10 11:11:11 using datePicker ?

thanks in advance
srinath

Comment: Solved !!!. we need to concat all the parameters and parse with new Date() .

Comment: you can concat the parameters, but this would be error prone.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [Data binding](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding) in Grails.  Data binding happens automatically with domain objects when you say `Book b = new Book(params)`  or if you use a Command Object.

```
def myAction = { BookCommand bookCommand -> 
    //bookCommand is already bound and validated by now
}
```

You can also manually invoke `bindData(...)` in your controller ([documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html)) if you want to.  Most likely you'll just want to use bindData like this:

```
def myAction = {
    ...
    bindData(myDomainObject, params, ['date1'])
    ...
    myDomainObject.save()
    ...
}
```